# Managing packages and subpackages in java / eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, package

i am trying to manage my packages in java using eclipse.
I have the package 'Task1' and 'Task1.m'. The Task1.m is the subpackage of Task1.
So i copied the class main.java, sandbox.java, color_fs.glsl and color_vs.glsl into the new created package 'task1.m' without done any changes with the code.
Means that my 'task1' and 'task1.m' packages contain similar sourcecode.

Now my problem :
If i try to run the 'task1.m' code, the outcome is not like intended. I want to have the same result like if i run the 'task1' package.
Here are some Screenshots :

[image: Running the Task1.m package]

[image: Running the Task1 package]

How is it possible to change the 'task1.m' package to have the same outcome like the 'task1' package?

Comment: just moving the files won't do, you have also to change the package declaration inside the source files.

Comment: also how are that .glsl files loaded inside the code ? you have to look up the method used because it might refer to some missing files

Comment: The package declaration is already done. The classes main and sandbox in the package task1.m are already referreing to package Task1.m. The classes of Task1 are referreing to package task1.

Comment: Oh Pievis, thank you so much. Indeed there was a false refer in the .glsl ! Fixed it and solved it!